# Clear textbox in "Angular4"

Tags: angular

How to clear textbox in Angular4? I am noob and have just made a simple login form. clicking on "Submit button", I want to clear the credentials entered while login.

My **login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xyz',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;
  onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    // code here to clear textbox

  }
  constructor() { }
  obj = {
    myname: 'Jay'
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post code you are using'

Comment: Is this just your code?

Comment: Just paste your code and select it and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: yes. and my login.component.html contains one textbox , password and submit button.

Comment: Paste your whole code here https://justpaste.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="username">
<input [(ngModel)]="password" type="password">
<button type="submit" (click)="login()">Submit</button>
```

Then in your `component.ts`:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    username;
    password;

    login() {
        // Perform your login

        // Then finally
        this.username = '';
        this.password = '';
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohjfyw

This one is so basic, you could have referred the angular docs before posting here.

There are other cleaner ways to do it (Using Angular Forms), but this one is the basic.

Comment: It stated in console box that while using [{ngModel)] inside the form tag, we have to specify [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: Just remove the wrapping form tag. Editing the answer

Comment: Was helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xyz',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;
  obj = {
    myname: 'Jay'
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    this.obj.myname = '';

  }
}
```

Your template should look something like this:

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="obj.myname">
    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use template forms you can do it this way

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  // clear textbox or input in html
  obj.myname: '';
}
```

If you use reactive forms you can do it with form.reset() or form.patchValue()

Comment: I think you meant  obj.myname = ""

Comment: yes, didn't realize it was a : instead of a = when I copied the code from OP. Thanks for catching that one.